# JQuery trigger/click on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, click

Trying to execute a click event on a button:

```
$(".pReload", $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent()).trigger();
```

or

```
$(".pReload", $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent()).click();
```

However, it is not executing. The button is loaded dynamically. Is there any way I can use .live?

Comment: You shouldn't ever chain that many `parent()` calls together.  Add an `id` or a `class` to whatever element you're trying to select, then use `$('#myElementID')` or `$('.myElementClass')`

Comment: @NRohler: Or use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a .live click function for the dynamic button. The .click(); responded afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.pReload').parent().parent().parent().parent().live('click', function(){
      // Your code
});
```

Hope it helps, all though it would be better if you assigned a class or id to the element youre trying to select with all the parent calls.

Comment: That binds a function to a click event to all future parent, parent, parent, parents of $('.pReload')... Don't think this is what the asker wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".pReload", $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent()).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the button in a $.ajax call? If so you can use a callback in the success method:

```
$.ajax({
 success: function({ $('.Preload')....});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **parents()** method with **eq()** together, but the best solution is to have id for target element

```
var target = $('#target').parents('div').eq(-1);
```

See the work example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mikhailov/U8rXV/1/

Comment: The button/link that needs to be clicked is dynamically added to the page. If if was a .click function i would use .live but this is a triggered click.